# Find parameter a for which..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratic-forms

> Find parameter $a$ for which $$\frac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$$ takes all real values for $x \in  \mathbb{R}$

I have equated the function to a real value, say, k
which gets me a quadratic in x. I have then put $D\geq 0$ (since $x \in \mathbb{R}$) which gets me $a \geq -9/16$

How do I proceed further to get other parameter for $a $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find $a$ so that the equation

$$y= \frac{a x^2+3x -4}{-4x^2+3x+a}$$

has a root which is in the domain of the function

The discriminant must be $\geq 0$ for all $y$

$$(9+16a)y^2+\left(4a^2+46\right)y +(9+16a)\geq 0$$

This is the case if its discriminant is negative and $9+16a>0$

$$16 (-7+a) (-1+a) (4+a)^2<0$$

which says $a$ must be in the interval $(1,7)$

Answer (score -1):

$ a \geq -9/16$ is not correct.  For $ a \leq -9/16$ the domain of the function $f(x)=\frac{ax^2+3x-4}{a+3x-4x^2}$ is $ \mathbb R.$

Comment: @Fre I don't think the question asks about *the dunctions domain*, but rather about when it is surjective. It is written "takes all the values..." .

Comment: @Anvit Is that an open interval or an ordered pair?\

Comment: @DonAntonio: for $ a \leq -9/16$ the domain is all of $ \mathbb R.$ and we have $f(x) \to -\frac{a}{4}$ as $x \to \pm \infty$. Hence, $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: @Fred Exactly my point: the function being surjective (or not)  isn't addressed here.

Comment: For example, for $\;a=0\;$, we get that if $\;k\in\Bbb R\;$ , then $$\frac{3x-4}{3x-4x^2}=k\iff 4kx^2+3(1-k)x-4=0$$and the above has a solution for  *any*  $\;k\in\Bbb R\;$ ,  as the last one is an upwards parabola which is always positive... We're just left with the task, in this example, of checking whether for some value $\;k\in\Bbb R\;$ we **must have** $\;x=0,\,\frac34\;$ , as this two points are *not* in the function's domain...

Comment: @Anvit According to your question **it must be an interval**, as it doesn't make any sense to ask for the values of a single real parameter and as solution to write down an ordered pair...!